# Submit input on enter in AngularJS form

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to complete or submit an input on enter press instead of clicking a submit button. Is this possible purely through a directive? Or must I add some JS?

Here's my input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='main.input' placeholder='some text' required=''/>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the whole form?

Comment: Use ngSubmit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ng-keyup` native directive on the input and fire up `ng-submit` on the form:

```
<form ng-submit="submitFunc()">
    <input type="text" ng-model='main.input' placeholder='some text' required='' ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && submitFunc()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***ng-submit*** to submit your form on ***enter button click***. See the example below,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.text = 'hello';
        $scope.submit = function() {
          if ($scope.text) {
            $scope.enterText = this.text;
            $scope.text = '';
          }
        };
      }
    ]);
</script>
<div ng-app="submitExample">
  <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Enter text and hit enter:
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <pre>list={{enterText}}</pre>
  </form>
</div>
```